# recording audio or video from google hangouts

Tags: 14.04, video, google-hangouts, audio-recording

How can I record audio or video coming from a google hangouts session?  Any recommended programs for linux and how to do it?

PS: I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 64bit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using OBS with no video sources set, recording in mkv format

```
sudo apt install snapd
sudo snap install obs-studio
```

Can keep them as mkv or can convert them to mp3; there is no big difference in file size (for 10fps, 640x480):

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 xxx xxx 186151 Nov 19 09:39 '2018-11-19 09-39-13.mkv'
-rw-r--r-- 1 xxx xxx 178756 Nov 19 09:39 '2018-11-19 09-39-13.mkv.mp3'
```

To convert to mp3, navigate to records directory and execute:

```
for i in *.mkv ; do ffmpeg -i "$i" -acodec libmp3lame -metadata TITLE="${i%.mkv}" "${i%.mkv}.mp3" ;done
```

Answer (score 1):

I think a screen recorder that can record the sound output from the computer is what you want. Make the Hangouts session full screen and use RecordMyDesktop from the Software Center.

Here's the link: https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/quantal/gtk-recordmydesktop/

Comment: It perfectly records my voice and screen, but you can't hear other speakers on the video.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it yet but Audio Recorder can probably do this:

Packages:
https://launchpad.net/~audio-recorder/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

Source:
https://launchpad.net/~audio-recorder